# How can I use a DataStore in a RavenDB trigger?

Tags: ravendb

I have a PutTrigger in which I would like to do some rather complex logic.
(Including reading other documents and do different stuff depending on the values in those other documents)

Because of the complexity, I would like work with my own domain objects, rather than with RavenJObjects. To get my domain objects in the same form as on the client-side, I need the same conventions to be applied when reading the entities.

So in summary: I need to use a DocumentStore in a PutTrigger.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that.  The `DocumentStore` class is part of the RavenDB client api, which doesn't exist on the server.  In a nutshell, the plugin API that runs on the server is a completely different beast than the client API that you're use to.  There is no concept of session, conventions, or other items you're used to finding from the client.

In a put trigger, you have access to the database via a property called `Database`, which is a `DocumentDatabase` type.  The database is completely unaware of entities - it strictly works with documents, which is why everything is in `RavenJObject`.

If you want to work with your own classes in a put trigger, that's fine.  But you'll need to handle the serialization aspect on your own.

Here are some examples to illustrate:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // etc...
}

public class TestTrigger : AbstractPutTrigger
{
  public override void OnPut(string key, RavenJObject document, RavenJObject metadata, TransactionInformation transactionInformation)
  {
    // example of editing the current document being stored
    if (key.StartsWith("foos/"))
    {
        Foo foo = document.Value<Foo>();
        foo.Name = "whatever";  // manipulate foo however you want

        // now you have to replace the items in the doc so it saves properly
        RavenJObject newDoc = RavenJObject.FromObject(foo);
        foreach (var item in document)
            document[item.Key] = newDoc[item.Key];
    }

    // example of loading and manipulating a different document
    using (Database.DisableAllTriggersForCurrentThread())
    {
        var doc = Database.Get("foos/1", transactionInformation);
        Foo foo = doc.DataAsJson.Value<Foo>();
        foo.Name = "whatever";
        RavenJObject newDoc = RavenJObject.FromObject(foo);
        Database.Put("foos/1", null, newDoc, doc.Metadata, transactionInformation);
    }
  }
}
```

You might want to re-think whether you really want to use a server-side trigger.  It might be easier for you to use a [client-side listener](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/advanced/client-side-listeners), such as an `IDocumentStoreListener`.  Typically server-side triggers are reserved for broad functionality that can apply to many different types of documents, such as the ones I wrote for [Temporal Versioning](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-TemporalVersioning), or [Indexed Attachments](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-IndexedAttachments).